# when using materialize.css select element does not appear

Tags: css, materialize

I am expecting something obvious, however I have actually spent quite some time trying to figure this out.

It is ONLY select elements that does not get displayed. I have tried using both local and CDN materialize 1.0.0, neither of them works. I've tried creating select elements without using the example from materialize as well. Inspecting developer tools, the select element and option elements are visible.

When commenting materialize.css out, select element will be displayed and it fetches all responses succesfully and runs the materialize.js file.

This is the element styles when using the materialize.css.

```
element.style {
}
select {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 3rem;
}
select {
    display: none;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif; OVERRIDEN
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.15;
    margin: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit; OVERRIDEN
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
user agent stylesheet
select {
    border-radius: 0px; OVERRIDEN
    border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169); OVERRIDEN
}
user agent stylesheet
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    box-sizing: border-box; OVERRIDEN
    align-items: center;
    white-space: pre;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    color: black;
    background-color: white; OVERRIDEN
    cursor: default;
    border-width: 1px; OVERRIDEN
    border-style: solid; OVERRIDEN
    border-color: initial; OVERRIDEN
    border-image: initial; OVERRIDEN
}
user agent stylesheet
select {
    border-radius: 5px; OVERRIDEN
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial; OVERRIDEN
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none; OVERRIDEN
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block; OVERRIDEN
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em; OVERRIDEN
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}
```

and this is my index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Skater-demo</title>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css CDN-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!-- Import materialize.css LOCAL
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./materialize/css/materialize.css">   
    -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
    </div>

    <select>
        <option>I will not be displayed</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created select examples with materialize.css check it out [here](https://github.com/georgioupanayiotis/JS-Scripts/blob/master/Materialize-Selects-Example.html)

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Materialize Selects Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js">
  </script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
        <select>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Fruit</option>
          <option value="1">Mango</option>
          <option value="2">Orange</option>
          <option value="3">Apple</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Materialize Multi Select</label>
        <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Fruit</option>
          <option value="1">Mango</option>
          <option value="2">Orange</option>
          <option value="3">Apple</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Select with Optgroup</label>
        <select>
          <optgroup label="Fruits">
            <option value="1">Mango</option>
            <option value="2">Orange</option>
            <option value="3">Apple</option>
          </optgroup>

          <optgroup label="Vegs">
            <option value="4">Brinjal</option>
            <option value="5">Potato</option>
            <option value="6">Tomato</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Select with images</label>
        <select class="icons">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Technology</option>
          <option value="1" data-icon="/html5/images/html5-mini-logo.jpg" class="circle">
            HTML</option>
          <option value="2">JavaScript</option>
          <option value="3">CSS</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Browser default Select</label>
        <select class="browser-default">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Fruit</option>
          <option value="1">Mango</option>
          <option value="2">Orange</option>
          <option value="3">Apple</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Disabled Materialize Select</label>
        <label>Disabled Materialize Select</label>
        <select disabled>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Fruit</option>
          <option value="1">Mango</option>
          <option value="2">Orange</option>
          <option value="3">Apple</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label>Disabled Browser default Select</label>
        <select class="browser-default" disabled>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Fruit</option>
          <option value="1">Mango</option>
          <option value="2">Orange</option>
          <option value="3">Apple</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am stubborn so I have been comparing our code for an hour or so. I cannot make select elements work in any way with materialize version 1.0.0. However I cannot seem to make it work in your version without the   <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  </script>. Do you mind elaborate it in the answer? :)

Comment: Firstly, you need a form in order to work, also you can add your select options on my code like this :
<div class="row">
     <label>Your Select options</label>
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Materialize Select</label>
    </div>
let me know if you sort that out ...